# Database design: many2many relationship for self referencing FK

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

My question can be demonstrated using the classic "employees" self referencing table, where manager_id is the FK related to the employee_id (PK). Another table is "authorizations".

What if authorizations are only relevant to managers and not to non-managers?
Assuming I create a junction table of "manager authorizations", can this table connect to employees.manager_id even though it's not unique?

Or must I separate managers to another table, even though they have the exact same attributes as non-managers?

Comment: no need to separate manager to another table.

Comment: What should be the relationship between managers and authorizations then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this structure [Employees Structure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/sakila-structure.html). It manages a complex situation (a manager is responsible of one or more departement) and records are historical (from_date, to_date).

Try to modify this structure as follow:

- departments becomes authorizations
- dept_emp becomes the associative table auth_emp
- remove dept_manager

A FK must always refer to a PK so connecting auth_emp to employee by manager_id is not possible (think to null references).

The decision to split or not employees that are manager to another table depends on your requirements (think about this: when a employee becomes a manager? An employee is a manager when at least another employee refers to him?).

If you want force the constraint that an employee_id registered in auth_emp refers to a manager you can use trigger on employee table. Obviously the trigger logic depends on your requirements.

Comment: Let's say a non-manager can never become a manager (because my case is different from employees/managers and I gave the example only for simplicity).
So you suggest connecting employees.emp_id to auth_emp.emp_id even though there are many employees who don't have any authorizations?

Comment: auth_emp.emp_id must to be connected to employees.emp_id. It's not a good strategy to connect it to employees.manager_id and in some db it is not allowed.